# Will RecyclerView be updated automatically when LiveData<List<Task>> is changed if I use BindingAdapter?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack

The following code is from the project architecture-samples, you can see it [here](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples).

Normally I observe `viewModel.items` and update adapter just like Code A.

In the project architecture-samples, the author use a customized `@BindingAdapter app:items`, I'm not sure if `(listView.adapter as TasksAdapter).submitList(items)` will be fired when `val items: LiveData<List<Task>>`  is changed, could you tell me?

```
val items: LiveData<List<Task>>
```

**tasks_frag.xml**

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/tasks_list"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                        app:items="@{viewmodel.items}" />
```

**TasksListBindings.kt**

```
@BindingAdapter("app:items")
fun setItems(listView: RecyclerView, items: List<Task>?) {
    items?.let {
        (listView.adapter as TasksAdapter).submitList(items)
    }
}
```

**TasksFragment.kt**

```
private fun setupListAdapter() {
        val viewModel = viewDataBinding.viewmodel
        if (viewModel != null) {
            listAdapter = TasksAdapter(viewModel)
            viewDataBinding.tasksList.adapter = listAdapter
        } else {
            Timber.w("ViewModel not initialized when attempting to set up adapter.")
        }
    }
```

**Code A**

```
viewModel.items.observe(this, Observer<List<Task>> {
            adapter.submitList(it)
})
```

Comment: Yes. because u trigger submitList in observe

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean that `@BindingAdapter app:items` will trigger `submitList` when the `items` is changed?